# Powerbi Top N and others for Pie Chart

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have the following data:

```
Country  Sales
1         20
1         30
1         10
2         25
2         80
3         200
3         4
4         20
5         30
```

I want to have top 2 country sales summed up and the rest

```
Country  Sales
2         105
3         204
Others    110
```

I want to display the summed up data in a pie chart.

```
Rank Sales = 
RANKX(ALL(Table[Country]),CALCULATE(sum(Table[Sales])))
```

What should I do ahead? The if condition is giving an error:

```
Rank Display = 
IF('DAX Measures'[Rank Sales]>2,"Other",'Table'[country])
```

Comment: Your *Rank Display* measure should be `=IF([Rank Sales]>2,"Other",MIN('Table'[Country]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create a new table, and paste this code:

```
CategorizationByRank =
VAR Summary_01 =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        VALUES ( 'Table'[Country] ),
        "Total", CALCULATE ( SUM ( 'Table'[Sales] ) )
    )
VAR Summary_02 =
    ADDCOLUMNS ( Summary_01, "Ranking", RANKX ( Summary_01, [Total] ) )
VAR TablesRankLess_And_Equal_To_2 =
    FILTER ( Summary_02, [Ranking] <= 2 )
VAR TablesRankGreater_Than_2 =
    ROW (
        "Country", "Others",
        "Total", SUMX ( FILTER ( Summary_02, [Ranking] > 2 ), [Total] ),
        "Ranking", 3
    )
VAR UnionAllRecords =
    UNION ( TablesRankGreater_Than_2, TablesRankLess_And_Equal_To_2 )
RETURN
    UnionAllRecords
```

And It produces this result:

[image: dfs]

Then you can put the fields directly into a pie chart, see the picture:

[image: PieChart]